# Zooming-in and zooming-out color spread on the whole map

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoserver

While zooming-in zooming-out of map red or orange color spread on the whole map but color will disappear as map tiles load on the map. I'm using openlayer and extjs for map loading. Is this is related with Geoserver SLD. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Please describe the problem more precisely.
Each SLD Role should have

```
<MinScaleDenominator>[value]</MinScaleDenominator>
<MaxScaleDenominator>[value]</MaxScaleDenominator>
```

or one of this.

And by the way, the order of XML nodes is important in an SLD. For example,

```
    <Rule>
       <Name>Medium</Name>
       <MinScaleDenominator>100000000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>200000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
       <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#0000CC</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
```

is correct, but

```
<Rule>
       <Name>Medium</Name>

       <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#0000CC</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>

       <MinScaleDenominator>100000000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>200000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
     </Rule>
```

may not work.